# An infinite number of primes in the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

> Does the sequence $ a_n = \left|-\frac{n^4}{6}+\frac{3n^3}{2}-\frac{13n^2}{3}+6n-1\right|$ contain an infinite number of primes?

I tried to find some theorems on this matter, but apparently the problem in general form is not solved. I will be happy with any results or suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Not known for any polynomial in one variable.

Comment: Those. there is not a single polynomial for which the problem was solved?

Comment: Not one. There are easy negatives, $3x^2 + 6$ or the like,

Comment: To the best of my understanding, current mathematical knowledge is "almost certainly yes, but we can't prove it". I don't know if there are any special methods that might apply.

Comment: This is understandable, I had in mind, of course, not trivial cases.

Comment: It was a major advance when Iwaniec showed $x^2 + y^4$ represented infinitely many primes, but that is still two variables. No proof for $x^2 + 1,$ possibly the oldest conjecture in this

Comment: Related  [Existence of polynomials of degree ≥2 which represent infinitely many prime numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208614/existence-of-polynomials-of-degree-geq-2-which-represent-infinitely-many-prim)

Comment: ... in fact, AFAIK, not only do we expect infinitely many primes, but we expect the number of primes to obey a law similar to the prime number theorem, and we can even compute the overall constant in that asymptotic estimate.

Comment: The closest result is [Green–Tao theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem#Extensions_and_generalizations) for polynomials with constant term 0.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think you are right. You should publish an article on it.

Answer (score 2):

[Bunyakovsky's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) says that if an irreducible polynomial $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ satisfies $1=\mathrm{gcd}\{f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4), \dots\}$ then $f(n)$ is prime for infinitely many $n$.  It has not been proven for any polynomial of degree greater than $1$. According to this we conjecture that $ a_n = \left|-\frac{n^4}{6}+\frac{3n^3}{2}-\frac{13n^2}{3}+6n-1\right|$ contains an infinite number of primes.